# pinescript to create a zone of a particular candle in a given range

Tags: timezone, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want a pinescript to mark zone of a 9:15 am & 10:30 candle every day in a given range, should be able to choose whether to select 9:15 candle or 10:30 candle

Wrote this code but it is not working

```
//@version=4
study("9:15-10:30 AM IST Zone", overlay=true)

ts = timestamp("GMT+5:30")

start_time = time(ts, session.regular, 915)
start_time = time(ts, session.regular, 1030)

bgcolor(start_time <= time and end_time >= time and low >= 100 and high <= 110 ? color.green : na, transp=80)
```

Comment: please use the appropriate tags when writing a question! You won't be able to reach the folks with the correct domain.specific knowledge otherwise.